# Написать функцию для вычисления первой буквы, которая встречается чаще всего в названии события(c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, структуры

Ниже подкрепил начало своего кода. Нужна помощь с написанием функции, которая вычислит первую(заглавную) букву, которая встречается чаще всего в названиях событий, которые вводит пользователь. Я очень долго мучаюсь с этим заданием, помогите кто может. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
const int size_p = 20;

struct ISTORIA
{
  char sobutie[size_p];
};

void main()
{
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  int n;
  cout << "Введите количество событий: ";
  cin >> n;
  ISTORIA* a = new ISTORIA[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin.get();
    cout << "Введите название события №" << i + 1 << endl;
    gets_s(a[i].sobutie);

  }
  cout << "Первая буква которая встречается чаще всего:" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Так вы даже не пытались что-то сделать... Что у вас конкретно не получается с решением данной задачи?

Comment: Это лишь определённый кусочек моей программы(без остальных лишний заданий, которые не относятся к данной функции), написать именно данную функцию я не знаю как, ни в дополнительной литературе, ни в интернете мне не удалось найти хоть чего-то подобного. Знаю, что возможно как-то не так искал или что-то ещё... Поэтому прошу помощи здесь, что бы разобраться с этим

Comment: так а что вам конкретно не понятно в реализации этой функции? Обходите полученную строку и инкременируете массив счётчиков. А в конце просто выбираете самое большое значение

Comment: Знаю, покажусь глупым. Но реально абсолютно не понимаю как это сделать. Можете сделать эту функцию или показать на каком-то примере, если вам не сложно и есть время?

Comment: если ее сделаю я - то чему научитесь вы? Сложного сдесь нет вообще ничего: если вы знаете циклы и массивы - сделаете (ну или попытаетесь, а если возникнут проблемы, то предоставите ваш код), а если не знаете - книгу в руки

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде

```
int ab[256] = {0};
cout << "Введите количество событий: ";
cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    ab[s[0]]++;
    }

int no = 0, mx = ab[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
    if (mx < ab[i]) {
        mx = ab[i];
        no = i;
        }

cout << char(no);
```

Comment: `ab[s[0]]++;` - рисковано, ведь `char` обычно знаковый.